# could not load file or assembly the located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: nuget, .net-assembly, nuget-package, assemblies, webview2

I updated our WebView2 version to the latest but I have one project still complaining about missing the old version assembly. My solution builds fine, but complains when I attempt to debug it.

I've verified:

1. All .csproj files reference the correct version
2. Nuget Package Manager shows correct version installed on projects
3. Correct .dll is referenced in the build output
4. Closed / Reopened VS (2019)
5. Cleaned / Rebuilt Solution

[image: project file]
[image: nuget window]
[image: error in application]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by manually downgrading the specific project to the version requested.